# How do i extract certain features from a dataframe when each row is a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataframe that is put together like this

```
Id features
1 [{'feature':'value1',feature2':'value2', 'feature3':'value3'}, {'feature1':'value1' etc.}] 
2 [{'feature1': 'value1', 'feature2':'value2', 'feature3':'value3'}, {feature1':'value1' etc.}]
```

How would I go about extracting a certain feature say 3, and extracting it. Feature 3 is an individual word, and I'd like to be able to combine them into sentences. As you can see in the dataframe, each row is in a list of dictionaries,and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

Input (Copy this ahead of running code as I use `df = pd.read_clipboard('\s+\s+')` in my code):

```
Id  features
1  [{'feature':'value1','feature2':'value2', 'feature3':'value3'}, {'feature1':'value1' etc.}] 
2  [{'feature1': 'value1', 'feature2':'value2', 'feature3':'value3'}, {'feature1':'value1' etc.}]
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_clipboard('\s+\s+')

#pass the string for the feature key you want to return values for. Pay attention to quotations (see what I pass when running the function).
def return_dataframe_dict_value(feature):
    df['new'] = ''
    df['new'] = df['new'].apply(list)
    for id_x, feature_x in zip(df['Id'],df['features'].str.split(feature)):
        i=0
        for y in feature_x:
            i+=1
            if i > 1:
                a = y.split("'")[1].split("'")[0]
                df.loc[id_x-1,'new'].append(a)


return_dataframe_dict_value("'feature1'")
df
```

Output:

```
    Id  features                                            new
0   1   [{'feature':'value1','feature2':'value2', 'fea...   [value1]
1   2   [{'feature1': 'value1', 'feature2':'value2', '...   [value1, value1]
```

In order to access any row and item in the list. For example access the second item in the second row with:

```
a = df['new'][1][1]
a
```

That will return 'value1'.